# jsp form and servlet with Angular.js validation

Tags: java, javascript, angularjs, jsp, servlets

I try to do a `jsp` form which would appeal to the the `servlet` after the `Angular.js` validation .

I have 3 main files -

**default.jsp**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<!-- JS -->
<script src="js/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="validationApp" ng-controller="mainController">
    <div class="container">

        <!-- =================================================================== -->
        <!-- FORM ============================================================== -->
        <!-- =================================================================== -->

        <!-- pass in the variable if our form is valid or invalid -->
        <form action="AfterFormServlet" method="POST" name="userForm"
            ng-submit="submitForm(userForm.$valid)" novalidate>

            <!-- FIRST NAME -->
            <div class="form-group"
                ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.name.$invalid && !userForm.name.$pristine }">
                <label>First name</label> <input type="text" name="name"
                    class="form-control" ng-model="user.name"
                    ng-pattern="/^[a-z ,.'-]+$/i" required>
                <p ng-show="userForm.name.$invalid && !userForm.name.$pristine"
                    class="help-block">Enter a valid last first name.</p>
            </div>    
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>    
        </form>    
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**AfterFormServlet.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class AfterFormServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/AfterFormServlet")
public class AfterFormServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public AfterFormServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("Hi");
    }

}
```

**app.js**

```
// create angular app
var validationApp = angular.module('validationApp', []);

// create angular controller
validationApp.controller('mainController', function($scope) {

    // function to submit the form after all validation has occurred            
    $scope.submitForm = function(isValid) {

        // check to make sure the form is completely valid
        if (isValid) {
            alert('Thanks, your order was Sent');
        }
        else {
            alert('Invalid form');
        }

    };

});
```

After I run it I get into the form , fill the required fields , click on the `submit` and it get into the servlet even though the validation failed .

How to make it work ?

**Update:**

following @ug_ suggestion  -

```
<form action="" active="AfterFormServlet" method="POST" name="userForm"
             ng-submit="submitForm(userForm.$valid);" novalidate>
```

make the validation but doesn't get into the `servlet` .

And -

```
<form action="AfterFormServlet" method="POST" name="userForm"
             ng-submit="submitForm(userForm.$valid);" novalidate>
```

cause the validation take affect but it get into the `servlet` even though the validation failed .

Comment: My suggestions: change form action to be `action=""` and return true with `ng-submit`. Also quick question, does the alert show?

Comment: @ug_ : can you explain me how to write that ?  and yeap the `alert` is  shown .

Answer (score 2):

You don't have an `action` attribute for your form, this means that when using the `ng-submit` directive it will prevent the default behavior causing the form to not submit. Info about it here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit .

**Fix:**

Add the `action=""` attribute to your form tag.

```
<form active="AfterFormServlet" action="" method="POST" name="userForm"
        ng-submit="submitForm(userForm.$valid)" novalidate>
```

*Also I noticed you have some attribute called `active`, I'm not sure if this was just a mistype and is suppose to be `action` or if it is related to something else you got going on, that isn't part of the post.*

**Edit:**
After looking a bit more I think you should just rework your code a little bit. It seems like a better flow to not use a submit button type but instead just send the submit behavior to a function where you validate the form. So it would look something like this:

```
$scope.submitForm = function(isValid) {

    // check to make sure the form is completely valid
    if (isValid) {
        alert('Thanks, your order was Sent');
        $scope.userForm.submit();
    }
    else {
        alert('Invalid form');
    }
};
```

and your html:

```html
<!-- CHANGE HERE -->
<form action="AfterFormServlet" method="POST" name="userForm" novalidate>
    <!-- FIRST NAME -->
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.name.$invalid &&  userForm.name.$pristine }">
        <label>First name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" ng-model="user.name" ng-pattern="/^[a-z ,.'-]+$/i" required>
        <p ng-show="userForm.name.$invalid && !userForm.name.$pristine" class="help-block">Enter a valid last first name.</p>
    </div>    
    <!-- CHANGE HERE -->
    <button ng-click="submitForm(userForm.$valid)" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>    
</form>
```

Alternatively you could use the `$http` provider in angular to submit your form via AJAX and it wouldn't refresh the page.

Comment: After your edit- still , it doesn't enforce the validation  .